# Inplace matrix multiplication __imatmul__ returns modified object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

The class is pretty simple:

```py
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return Matrix(Matrix.multiply(self.values, other.values))

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        return Matrix(Matrix.multiply(self.values, other.values))

    def __imatmul__(self, other):
        return self.__matmul__(other)

    @staticmethod
    def multiply(mat1, mat2):
        return [[sum(mat1 * mat2 for mat1, mat2 in zip(mat1_row, mat2_col))
                 for mat2_col in zip(*mat2)]
                for mat1_row in mat1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Matrix values="{self.values}">'
```

For some reason, when playing with `__imatmul__` dunder method I'm not able to make it transform the initial matrix - IDs differ:

```py
mat1 = Matrix([[11, 12], [13, 14]])
orig_id_mat1 = id(mat1)
print(f'mat1: {mat1}, id: {orig_id_mat1}')
mat2 = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
orig_id_mat2 = id(mat2)
print(f'mat2: {mat2}, id: {orig_id_mat2}')

mat1 @= mat2
modif_id_mat1 = id(mat1)
print(f'mat1: {mat1}, id: {modif_id_mat1}')
```

Output:

```
mat1: <Matrix values="[[11, 12], [13, 14]]">, id: 24458192
mat2: <Matrix values="[[1, 2], [3, 4]]">, id: 24458384
mat1: <Matrix values="[[47, 70], [55, 82]]">, id: 24458608
```

What should be changed in `__imatmul__`'s implementation?

Comment: Well, yeah. Your `__imatmul__` doesn't modify the object. There's nothing in there that would do that. Were you expecting Python to do the modification for you?

Comment: Your `__rmatmul__` is broken, too - it acts like `self` is the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `__imatmul__` is just an alias of `__matmul__`. It doesn't do anything in-place because you didn't code it to.

First off, you should understand what the in-place versions of operators do. The expression `a @= b` is generally (but not always) equivalent to `a = type(a).__imatmul__(a, b)`. It is just another function call. This way, you can do "in-place" operations on immutable objects that create a new result but preserve the name.

Your call to `__mult__` is doing just that: it creates and returns a new object, which you replace your matrix with.

A simple way to do the operation in-place is to do

```
def __imatmul__(self, other):
    self.values = self.multiply(self.values, other.values)
    return self
```

You can also define `__matmul__` in terms of `__imatmul__` to make maintenance easier:

```
def __matmul__(self, other):
    new = type(self)(self.values)
    return type(new).__imatmul__(new, other)
```

Finally, you may want to fix your implementation of `__rmatmul__`:

```
def __rmatmul__(self, other):
    return type(self).__matmul__(other, self)
```

Comment: `return other @ self` is still a broken `__rmatmul__` - it ends up in infinite recursion if `@` ever actually calls it. The right move there would be to remove `__rmatmul__` entirely unless you actually want to support mixed-type `@`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Good catch. I was trying to be lazy. `__rmatmul__` can be useful when dealing with subtypes (although you don't really need it on the parent type). I've fixed the implementation to avoid infinite recursion.